# igraph not writing attribute to graphml in Python

Tags: python-3.x, networking, igraph

I have an igraph graph object, `g`, with the following list of attributes:

```
IN: g.vertex_attributes()
OUT: ['Label',  'mentioned',  'retweeted',  'community_id']
```

I then try to create a new attribute from an existing pandas dataframe as follows:

```
IN: g.vs['profile_status'] = y['profile_status']
```

... where `y` looks like this:

```
IN: y.head()
OUT:   user.screen_name    profile_status
0   username1   User profile active
1   username2   User profile active
2   username3   Account deleted or suspended
3   username4   User profile active
4   username5   User profile active
```

...resulting in an attribute list that now looks like this with the new attribute added:

```
IN: g.vertex_attributes()
OUT: ['Label',  'mentioned',  'retweeted',  'community_id', 'profile_status']
```

However, the `profile_status` field is not being written to the graphml file when I run this:

```
IN: g.write_graphmlz(NETWORK_OUTPATH)
```

Opening the graphml file in a text editor shows that there is no `profile_status` field anywhere.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

igraph appears to have trouble with string attributes so converting the string values into integer codes did the trick. Here's how I did it:

```
# Generate list of statuses and their integer codes
possible_statuses = {y:x for x,y in enumerate(y['profile_status'].unique())}
print(possible_statuses)
y['profile_status_code'] = y['profile_status'].apply(lambda x: possible_statuses[x])

g.vs['profile_status_code'] = y['profile_status_code']

# Write network to file
g.write_graphmlz(NETWORK_OUTPATH)
```